# Start/Stop Windows Service or Linux Daemon from .Net

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, daemon

Is there a platform agnostic way to start/stop Windows Services or Linux daemons from a .Net app?

I have a Blazor Server app, and I'd like it to be able to start/stop a service/daemon that I created.

My service will be created following [.NET Core and systemd](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-and-systemd/), with both `UseSystemd()` and `UseWindowsService()` so that it'll be usable on both Linux and Windows.

There's [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) but it seems to be Windows only.

Comment: I'd do it the other direction-- create a windows / linux service that actively checks requests, rather than passively receiving them.  I'd save requests in log files, and have my service periodically chec,k the appropriate folder for new files with instructions to act on.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 It's a possibility indeed. I would still be interested in knowing if it's possible directly through .Net to start/stop services/daemons. Right now I either run `sc start myservice` or `systemctl start myservice` depending on the environment.